# Return array and function that returns another array together JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

I'm currently trying to return an `array` with some values and a `function` that returns another `array` as well. How do I do it that my returns is basically `2 arrays` instead of `1 array` and `1 function`

Example

```
const array1 = [a, b, c]

const function = () => {
  if(something) {
    somevalues.map(e => {
      return ( 
        <div>{e}<div>
     )
   })
  } else {
    othervalues.map(f => {
      return ( 
        <div>{f}<div>
     )
   })
  }
} 

return [...array1, function] ??
```

function in the example obviously returns function instead of its own return, how do I fix that?

Comment: I'm confused. You say you are trying to return an array and a function and then you are saying you want to return two arrays instead of an array and a function? What is it now? *"function in the example obviously returns function instead of its own return, how do I fix that?"* *Call* the function?

Comment: Change `function` into a valid variable like `X`

Comment: Rename `function` into something like `func` and in returned array use `func()` instead of `func`

Comment: @FelixKling I'm trying to return only values of the function so I end up in the result with array of variables from `array1` and variables that the `function` return

Comment: @EzioMercer that returns `undefined`

Comment: @Fill because you didn't define `e` and `f`. Try `'e'` and `'f'` as a string for test

Comment: @EzioMercer lets say e and f are defined. In my case I'm actually mapping through some values of e and mapping through some values of f. I will update the question now.

Comment: *"that returns `undefined`"* I assume you are referring to calling your function? Should the function always return something? If yes then you need to fix your function.

Comment: Also `something` isn't going to do much

Comment: You need to `return` the return values of the `Array#map` calls from your function and you need to spread those values into the result array: `[...array1, ...func()]`. A (non-async) function that doesn't contain a `return` statement will always return `undefined`

Comment: I want my result to look as one big `array` with values from `array1` and values that are being returned from the `function`

Comment: What function does `return [...array1, function] ??` belomg to?

Comment: @zer00ne query rendering in gatsby, I think thats irrelevant

Comment: @Fill to which question are you replying to? I have only JavaScript as the context of this OP, I don't recall Gatsby as a tag nor any mention of it until now.

Comment: @zer00ne regarding what function does `return [...array1, function] ??` In any case, The solution @Felix has provided worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- actually return something from your function. If you don't return the return values of `somevalues.map(...)` and `othervalues.map(...)` then your function will return `undefined`.
- call the function to get its return value
- spread the return value into the result array, just like you do with the static array.

Example:

```
const array1 = [a, b, c]

const outerFunction = () => {

  const innerFunction = () => {
    if(something) {
      return somevalues.map(e => (<div>{e}<div>));
//    ^^^^^^
    } else {
      return othervalues.map(f => (<div>{f}<div>));
//    ^^^^^^
    }
  } 

  return [...array1, ...innerFunction()];
//                   ^^^             ^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const something = true;

const func = () => {
  if(something) {
    return 'e';
  } else {
    return 'f';
  }
};

console.log([...array1, func()]); //[ "a", "b", "c", "e" ]
```